# undefined value inside props.location - React Routing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to send complete user info from a link tag. so main idea is if a user clicks on user card he is directed to above link and he can see that page and i am passing the object from link tag.
But console is returning `undefined`.
please help!

if you need any other code let me know.

Please suggest if there is any other way of achieving this target.

App.js

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/detail" element={<Detail />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Detail(index.js)

```
function Detail(props) {
console.log(props.location);

return(<h1>hi</h1>);

}

export default Detail;
```

In some other file,

```
const location = {
    pathname: "/detail",
    search: `?name=${c.name}`,
    state: c,
  };

 <Link to={location}>
</Link>
```

Answer (score 2):

Location information doesn't come through the props, unless you define a custom component and give it the location yourself.

To get the location object in your components, you should use the [`useLocation`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-location) hook from react-router-dom

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

function Detail(props) {
  const location = useLocation();
  console.log(location);

  return(<h1>hi</h1>);
}

export default Detail;
```

Comment: this gives data. But the `state` inside is `null`. any idea? @Samathingamajig